# Magnetic Field Interfering with Radio Waves

Tags: coil, wireless-charging, nrf24l01

i am currently building a device that requires a NRF24L01 module to send radio waves to another NRF24L01 to be picked up and interpreted. This is a using an arduino running a code to transmit data via NRF and another arduino above it to receive those signals as seen below. 
[image]
Everything works perfectly until the wireless charging coil which is in between the 2 NRF modules is turned on. After supplying power to the coil which powers the arduino above to receive NRF data from below no data is being perceived at all. Normally colors are supposed to change when the mouse moves, but instead the same color from what was left when other experimenting took place is the only color lingering as seen below. 
[image]
After doing some experimenting and moving the arduino away from the coil and plugging it in all signals were being sent successfully. As long as the receiving end of the coil (or receiving end of the NRF module i'm not sure which one) wasn't too close to the transmitting end of the coil. Seen below are positions of the receiving NRF module where signals send from the transmitter were received successfully.
[image]
[image]
[image]
I understand this may not make a lot of sense so here is a short video describing what is happening. [Video about problem](https://youtu.be/lZ3xvUVnwl0)

My question here is mainly what can i do to fix this issue? will changing the radio frequency from 2.4 GHz to 2.5 GHz or anywhere in between make a difference? Can i mount the NRF transmitter module on the green wall seen in the pictures so that it is above the wireless power coils? or do i need to use a different method of communication?

Here is the coil in question [Coil](https://www.robotshop.com/en/12v-600ma-wireless-charging-module.html#Dimensions). With the current arrangement when measuring with my multi-meter the receiving end is getting 0.004A or 4mA and the transmitting end is taking 0.01A or 10mA all at 12V. The rated current for the receiving end is 600mA and im not sure how much is being taken in from the transmitting coil when 600mA is reached up top.

here is the data sheet
[datasheet](https://elecfreaks.com/estore/download/EF03093-XKT-510.pdf). Apparently the coils operate at 0-5MHz

UPDATE: The NRF module isn't receiving data because of the data being obstructed by the magnetic field, but rather because the magnetic field is messing with the receiving module itself. In order to solve the issue im going to have to move the NRF module higher up from the circuit board and data sends perfectly.

Comment: Can you add some more information about the wireless charging coils? What frequency do they use? Is there any form of core material (like in a toothbrush) or are they air cored? How much power is being transferred through them?

Comment: Okay, I updates to add more information about the coil at the bottom of the post.

Comment: also is there an equation to calculate the frequency the coils operate at? if so can you tell me i would like to learn it and try it out

Comment: Is the LED bar going to spin?  Is that why the coils are located where they are?

Comment: You seem to have good range on your NRF modules, have you tried placing them so that their fields are orthogonal to the power coils field?

Comment: LED bar will spin but i have not tried that. Im waiting for my new motherboards to come in so that i can ribbon cable from where the NRF transmitter is now up to a wall so it is in line and hopefully avoiding going through the magnetic field.

Comment: but that seems weird that no data, not even weird characters are received from what the transmitter is sending. The magnetic field cant be that big?

Comment: Both of your devices are operating in the near field, not the far field, AND in the near field of each other.  When in the near field it's easy to detune, swamp and/or saturate the other device, even when the frequencies are not very close.  The physics are different in the near field, it's not just "simple RF".

Comment: I guess shielding the charging coils will solve the problem. Do you have the possibility to do so or have you already tried?

Comment: can you shield a magnetic field?

Comment: Reese Houseknecht sort of, but not really. You can only divert it away and around from somewhere. And I think that only works with static magnetic fields, not dynamic ones.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's not shielding as such though, the magnetic field gets channelled through the material rather than through the space around it. The best geometry can be hard to work out, but I'd start with a cylinder of steel sheet/pipe a little bigger than the coil, and parallel to it, overlapping both coils. A second pipe/tube a bit shorter and inside the coils might help too.

Comment: It would still be nice to know the coil operating frequency. That isn't something you calculate with an equation, you have to ask the person who designed the coil/module what they chose, or look in the manual for the coil/module. Unfortunately I couldn't find a proper manual or datasheet for that coil.

Comment: So things im going to try are moving the transmitting NRF module so it is on the same plane as the receiving module and therefor hopefully allowing data to be received, and if that does not work then putting steel around the coils and inside the coils. But is there anything software i can change, or maybe find a different coil that operates at a frequency that wont disturb my data.

Comment: Magnetic fields work like a circuit. You can't "block" the field, but you can divert it into a lower impedance pathway. I'm not an expert in this, but I would try visualizing the field lines and adding an iron pathway in that area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an additional option for your design, consider adding blocking elements to separate the wireless transmission of power from signal transmission.  These could be Faraday cage style meshing dumped to ground or (possibly) some nickel based sheet metal stock.  If it's easier to just move the receiver for data transmission, do that.  If not, or if for some other reason you'd rather not move that receiver then maybe you can corral your signals using metal.

Here's a (wikipedia) example of EM shielding inside an old cell phone:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding#/media/File:Electromagnetic_shielding_inside_mobile_phone.jpg

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with what was truly going on for a couple of days it became apparent on how I need to fix this. At first it was thought that the message being transmitted from the NRF module was being messed up and therefor not being received. It is now known the coil was only messing with the receiving NRF module, but data could still be transferred through the magnetic field. This is because the frequencies both devices operate at are totally different. The solution here is to move the NRF module higher up relative to the wireless coils and everything works. Steel which is magnetic and could divert the magnetic field could have been placed around the coils, but because of the spinning that will soon happen the friction damage isn't really an option for me and was never tested.

Comment: I think this is better suited as an update to the original question.

Comment: Well since keeping the module around the coil and just changing frequencies didnt work this is my only option and therefore best solution if this happens to anyone else